# Can't sign into Github Desktop on arch linux after power outage -- "Cannot create an item in a locked collection"

Tags: linux, github-desktop

So I recently had a power outage, and it affected the whole neighborhood, but what made it worse was it (almost, thankfully) corrupted my external hard drive somehow (that was fixed, again, thankfully), and some temporary files on my arch linux install may have persisted when they shouldn't. I'm assuming the latter, as when I try to log into Github Desktop, the "authentication" fails with a very unhelpful error message: "Cannot create an item in a locked collection".
What's going on?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Hello, what did you try based on that error message?